# How to change an array to a JSON format with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array which is in the below format
`node=['ADSss|623', 'sss|635']`
I want this to be in a json format as below

```
[
    {
        "623": "ADSss"
    },
    {"635": "sss"

    }

]
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this? it is possible with map function, but i felt it is adding up too many lines of code

Comment: Please include what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you array only contain string of format `${value}|${key}`, you can map those to an object:

```
const result = node.map((arrayEl) => {
  // Split you array string into value and keys
  const [value, key] = arrayEl.split('|');
  // return an object key: value
  return {[key]: value}
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line :

```js
const node=['ADSss|623', 'sss|635'];
const json = node.reduce((p, n) => ({ ...p, [n.split('|')[1]]: n.split('|')[0] }), {});
const jsonArray = node.map(n => ({ [n.split('|')[1]]: n.split('|')[0] }));

console.log(json);
console.log(jsonArray);
```